# How to automate file upload on browserstack using nightwatch node js

Tags: node.js, selenium, browserstack

I am writing automation using Nightwatch node js. I have a test for uploading a file in my application and testing it locally works perfectly. However, when I test it using BrowserStack, BrowserStack cannot access the file in my local machine.

I have also tried setting FileDetector but it gives error saying setFileDetector is not a function on browser object.
I know this function is available for selenium driver object but I am javascript browser object for writing test scripts.

browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to perform the File Upload Operation for a file available on your local machine. You can review the link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#enhancements-uploads-downloads for more details.